# json_encode formatting not matching jQuery Calender format requirement

Tags: php, json

I am working with a jQuery calendar that expects this format of JSON:

```
string(138) "[{"title":"Event1","start":"2012-06-10"},{"id":222,"title":"Event2","start":"2012-06-20","end":"2012-06-22","url":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/"}]"
```

However, I am getting is this:

```
[{"title":"Event1","start":"2012-06-10"},{"id":222,"title":"Event2","start":"2012-06-20","end":"2012-06-22","url":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/"}]array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(6) "Event1" ["start"]=> string(10) "2012-06-10" } [1]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(222) ["title"]=> string(6) "Event2" ["start"]=> string(10) "2012-06-20" ["end"]=> string(10) "2012-06-22" ["url"]=> string(17) "http://yahoo.com/" } }
```

The issue is one says its a `string(138)`, while the other is an `array`.

Here is my code:

```
$myHolder = array();
$myHolder[] = array(
    'title' => "Event1",
    'start' => "$year-$month-10",
);
$myHolder[] = array(
    'id' => 222,
    'title' => "Event2",
    'start' => "$year-$month-20",
    'end' => "$year-$month-22",
    'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
);

echo json_encode(($myHolder));
```

Comment: I'm sure it has nothing to do with the problem, but why is the variable in parentheses in the `json_encode` function?

Comment: The first example block isn't valid JSON. It's not helpful if you mix in the var_dump output and forget to explain what you actually want.

Comment: Which jQuery calendar? Where can we review the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

This produces the exact string you're looking for:

```
ob_start();
var_dump( json_encode( $myHolder));
$output = trim( ob_get_clean());
```

However, I doubt it will be helpful to have the string length / format that `var_dump` produces as an input to a JS calendar. Nevertheless, if it's what you need, this is how you can get it.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gX4Kzh)

Comment: Where does the `""` that wraps it come from? Also, I imagine the OP is misinterpreting the docs, so I agree it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It comes straight from `var_dump`'s output.

Comment: Oh, duh. Which reinforces my belief this is based on a mistake.